# Re-directing System.out via a jsp page

Tags: jsp, redirect, system.out

I import several of my classes into jsp. I want to redirect `System.out` to a file via the jsp. The following method redirects if I execute the method from the console:

```
public String Write() {

    String str="";

    try {      
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("Xfile.txt");
        System.setOut(ps);

        System.out.println("helo world");
        ps.close();            
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println (ex.toString());
        str = ex.toString();
    }

    return str;
}
```

If I import the class in a jsp and execute the method, str is blank and the file "Xfile.txt" is not found anywhere. I run tomcat `tomcat-7.0.35` and `Apache 2.4.7`

Comment: It's not found? May be it's redirected to dev/null?

Comment: Your code works for me. The file Xfile.txt is created in the folder where the java process is started. In this case, it was created in Tomcat/bin .

Comment: You are correct. Wonder why "find" didn't find it. Oh well this really helps. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to create the file somewhere else, then use an absolute path. Within your web app, you can use the getRealPath  method.

Answer (score 0):

As per @rickz comment: *The file Xfile.txt is created in the folder where the java process is started. In this case, it was created in Tomcat/bin*